# phpldapadmin not loading php

Tags: php, ubuntu-16.04, php-5.6, apache2.4

For some reason my phpldapadmin doesn't want to work with my website and it says "If you are seeing this in your browser, PHP is not installed on your web server!!!" Which is not true as if the info.php file is navigated to like here it says php is enabled along with the ldap extension. The apache error log doesn't say anything about the error though.

Every other php page on my website works except phpldapadmin. I am really confused.

This is what I get when I run php -v

```
PHP 7.1.1-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) (built: Jan 20 2017 09:20:20) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.1.1-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: It can be webserver config problem. Have you tested info.php with source `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in the exact same folder where phpldapadmin is?

Comment: I put an info.php file in `/usr/share/phpldapadmin` but I get a 404 error when I try and access the page

Comment: /usr/share doesn't seem like proper webserver root, but of course, it depend on your config. What webserver do you use? Apache? Nginx?

Comment: I am running apache 2.4

Comment: So check the /etc/httpd.conf where points "DocumentRoot" and if the php is properly configured (like `LoadModule php??_module modules/libphp??.so`    
`AddHandler php??-script php`)

Comment: Php works on all my other pages except the phpldapadmin page

Comment: You said you got 404 error if you tried access the `info.php` in `/usr/share/phpldapadmin` which is clearly some missconfiguration. I can't help you without analysis... All your other pages means what? In which folders they live?

Comment: So for example my phpmyadmin or my forums all work and they use php. Im not 100% sure where my phpldapadmin root is though

Comment: But where the phpmyadmin or my forums sits in the filesytem? In which folders exactly?

Comment: My forum is in `/var/www/html` and I think phpmyadmin is in `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webserver's document root is `/var/www/html` and you have to place everything within this folder (may use subfolders `/var/www/html/phpmyadmin`, `/var/www/html/phpldapadmin`, etc.). Or you can define alias for certain purposes which can point to a folder outside document root. How to config an alias: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias

Everything else what's outside isn't accessible by webserver itself and neither can be processed by PHP.

Comment: All there is is an `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` but there is the same for phpldapadmin

Comment: And inside `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf`is?!? Hey, I'm asking about the configuration from the very begining, and you can't go a bit further a look into that file? I'm pretty sure, that `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` was there by default from installation and `Include /etc/phpldapadmin/apache.conf` was add by you, but you ommit the file itself. Am I right?

Comment: There is nothing related to aliases in my apache2.conf file and yes I added the phpldapadmin section to my file but it made no difference

Comment: Once again `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` is a file, so look into it. There is alias configuration directive for phpmyadmin. This file is included into apache.conf - that's why "Include" is there. Is that clear?

Comment: Analogically you have to create '/etc/phpldapadmin/apache.conf` file with proper configuration, if you want to include it by Include directive into main config file.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the wrong file, in my phpldapadmin apache.conf folder there is this `<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    Alias /phpldapadmin /usr/share/phpldapadmin/htdocs
</IfModule>`

Comment: I think the path should be `/usr/share/phpldapadmin/`. (Note - you should make exact copy of phpmyadmin/apache.conf into phpldapadmin/apache.conf and only alter paths according to phpldapadmin. If you did so, ommit this note...). After config changes are done, do not forget to restart apache.

Comment: You're welcome. (accept the answer if you're satisfied...)